# Excel Index Array Formula Slow

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have numbers randomly placed in a column:

[image]

I want to group all the numbers together in a new column. I use the following Array formula:

> {=INDEX($B:$B, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER($B:$B), ROW($B:$B)-MIN(ROW($B:$B))+1,
>   ""), ROWS(ZZ2:$ZZ$2)))}

But I have such 500 numbers in the source column. This make the formula processing very slow. How can I do this faster?

Comment: Don't use whole columns in array formulas. In your case `{=INDEX($B$1:$B$1000,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER($B$1:$B$1000),ROW($B$1:$B$1000),""),ROWS(ZZ2:$ZZ$2)))}` will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, any formula entered as an array formula or any formula that uses a function involving cyclic calculation (e.g. SUMPRODUCT, some variations of AGGREGATE, etc) should not use full column references. A cyclic calculation involving 10 rows makes 100 calculations; 1000 rows makes 1 million calculations. If you do the math for 1,048,576 rows and then compute the unnecessary calculations made on empty cells you will quickly see the wasted computing cycles that translate to 'calculation lag'.

So instead of using `B:B`, you can start with `B1` as the top cell in column B:B. The row with the last number in column B:B can be retrieved with,

```
MATCH(1E99, B:B)
```

So you can locate the last cell in column B:B with a number by INDEXing column B:B and using MATCH to find the row number.

```
INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E99, B:B))
```

To get a range simply join the two with a colon.

```
B1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E99, B:B))
'if you are starting your data at a significantly different row than row 1 then this would be better where you can easily set the starting row
INDEX(B:B, 1):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E99, B:B))
```

I prefer AGGREGATE's SMALL sub-function to array entered SMALL(IF... so my version of your formula would be,

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(INDEX(B:B, 1):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/SIGN(LEN(INDEX(B:B, 1):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))), ROW(1:1)))
```

That might look more complicated but it will reduce calculation lag to a minimum.